# How to come up with statistics that shows the total number of quizzes, total number of participants?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am developing a simple web application that provides the users with quizzes. since I am new to ASP.NET world, I am following the How to build Quiz Engine Video series on ASP.net website. My database design is to similar to the design used in these videos.
This is the [link of the first video](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/lesson-11-building-a-quiz-engine-1): 
Everything works fine with me, but I want now to develop a query that helps me to display a statistics to the Admin which shows:

1. Total number of quizzes in the system
2. Total number of participants in each quiz
3. Total number of participants in general in **daily basis, weekly basis, monthly basis and yearly basis (if possible)**

To clarify the last point, I want the admin to see the following:

1. total number of participant druing last week was: ......
2. total number of taken quizzes during last week was: .........
3. total number of taken quizzes during last month was: .........

I think something like this is very useful to know the usage of the system and to show the management how the system is efficient in the copmany.

The sechma of the database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Quiz](
    [QuizID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Quiz] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [QuizID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Quiz] ON
INSERT [dbo].[Quiz] ([QuizID], [Title], [Description]) VALUES (6, N'Safety', N'General Safety Test')
INSERT [dbo].[Quiz] ([QuizID], [Title], [Description]) VALUES (7, N'my title', N'my description')
INSERT [dbo].[Quiz] ([QuizID], [Title], [Description]) VALUES (9, N'General Safety Quiz2', N'Testing')
INSERT [dbo].[Quiz] ([QuizID], [Title], [Description]) VALUES (10, N'General Safety Quiz3', N'Testing #2')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Quiz] OFF


/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Question]    Script Date: 11/17/2011 00:44:38 ******/

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Question](
    [QuestionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Question] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Answer1] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Answer2] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Answer3] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Answer4] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [CorrectAnswer] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [AnswerExplanation] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [QuestionOrder] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [QuizID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Question] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [QuestionID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Question] ON
INSERT [dbo].[Question] ([QuestionID], [Question], [Answer1], [Answer2], [Answer3], [Answer4], [CorrectAnswer], [AnswerExplanation], [QuestionOrder], [QuizID]) VALUES (4, N'What is your name?', N'Mohammed ', N'Ali', N'Hassan', N'Husain', 1, N'My Name', 1, 6)
INSERT [dbo].[Question] ([QuestionID], [Question], [Answer1], [Answer2], [Answer3], [Answer4], [CorrectAnswer], [AnswerExplanation], [QuestionOrder], [QuizID]) VALUES (7, N'What is the definition of Safety?', N'Being Safe', N'Being in danger', N'Be careful', N'be careless', 1, N'Nothing', 1, 9)
INSERT [dbo].[Question] ([QuestionID], [Question], [Answer1], [Answer2], [Answer3], [Answer4], [CorrectAnswer], [AnswerExplanation], [QuestionOrder], [QuizID]) VALUES (8, N'What is the definition of Safety? ', N'Being Safe', N'Being Careless', N'Being Careful', N'Being in Dangerous', 1, N'Nothing to say', 1, 10)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Question] OFF
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[UserQuiz]    Script Date: 11/17/2011 00:44:38 ******/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserQuiz](
    [UserQuizID] [int] NULL,
    [QuizID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateTimeComplete] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [Score] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Username] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserQuiz] ([UserQuizID], [QuizID], [DateTimeComplete], [Score], [Username]) VALUES (NULL, 6, CAST(0x9F8F02D8 AS SmallDateTime), 100, N'SMP\ALMARHMS')
INSERT [dbo].[UserQuiz] ([UserQuizID], [QuizID], [DateTimeComplete], [Score], [Username]) VALUES (NULL, 6, CAST(0x9F8F02E3 AS SmallDateTime), 50, N'SMP\ALMARHMS')
INSERT [dbo].[UserQuiz] ([UserQuizID], [QuizID], [DateTimeComplete], [Score], [Username]) VALUES (NULL, 6, CAST(0x9F8F0333 AS SmallDateTime), 50, N'SMP\ALMARHMS')
INSERT [dbo].[UserQuiz] ([UserQuizID], [QuizID], [DateTimeComplete], [Score], [Username]) VALUES (NULL, 7, CAST(0x9F8F0335 AS SmallDateTime), 100, N'SMP\ALMARHMS')
```

By help from one of the guys here in this great community, I came up with one query that shows the number of participants in each quiz. This is the query:

```
SELECT     Q.QuizID, Q.Title, COUNT(*) AS Users
                                   FROM       dbo.UserQuiz AS UQ 
                                   INNER JOIN dbo.Quiz AS Q ON Q.QuizID = UQ.QuizID
                                   GROUP BY Q.QuizID, Q.Title
```

Now I need to modify it or to come up withe new query that gives me the above three points. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count for the last 7 days and the last 30 days, you could use something like this:

```
-- Count of Participants in the last 7 days 
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Q.UserName) 
FROM dbo.UserQuiz Q 
WHERE DateTimeComplete >= DATEADD(dd, -7, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) 

-- Count quizzes taken in the last 7 days 
SELECT COUNT(Q.QuizID) 
FROM dbo.UserQuiz Q 
WHERE Q.DateTimeComplete >= DATEADD(dd, -7, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) 

-- Count quizzes taken in the last 30 days 
SELECT COUNT(Q.QuizID) 
FROM dbo.UserQuiz Q 
WHERE Q.DateTimeComplete >= DATEADD(dd, -30, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

Note that if you want to count for calendar weeks and calendar months then you need to do a bit more work to filter the proper starting and ending date filters.

---

**EDIT:** Fixed the query syntax (1st answer posted without running it in SSMS) also I didn't notice at first that the UserQuiz.UserQuizID is nullable.  This column is therefore not what I would have expected it to be.

---

**EDIT #2:** As per OP's request, these three statistics can also be retrieved in a single query using sub-selects.  Sub-selects are necessary because of differences in either the filter criteria or the aggregations involved in counting each statistic (or both).

```
-- Combine three stats into one query using sub-selects...
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Q.UserName)  
 FROM dbo.UserQuiz Q  
 WHERE DateTimeComplete >= DATEADD(dd, -7, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))
 as ParticipantsLast7Days,
(SELECT COUNT(Q.QuizID)  
 FROM dbo.UserQuiz Q  
 WHERE Q.DateTimeComplete >= DATEADD(dd, -7, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))
 as QuizzesLast7Days,
(SELECT COUNT(Q.QuizID)  
 FROM dbo.UserQuiz Q  
 WHERE Q.DateTimeComplete >= DATEADD(dd, -30, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))
 as QuizzesLast30Days
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. However, I tried your queries, but no one of them worked with me. Sorry, but don't get me wrong. I am still new to the Web Development. For instance, I tried your first query in SQLServer Management Studio and I got the following error:                  Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: @MohammedAl-Ali - Sorry, my initial answer was done without the benefit of a test in SSMS.  I have fixed the errors.  The syntax is now correct.

Comment: It is OK. I could be able to fix the syntax. Now, I am just worrying about the result, because I got 0 as a result of all queries. I don't know why. I am working on figuring out the problem. I have data in the database, but still I got  zeros. Could you please help me with this issue?

Comment: Look at the dates in your sample data.  They are all too old.  You need to run an update to modify the dates in your sample data or change the number of days you want to go back.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Sorry for missing this thing. By the way, is it possible to put all of these queries in one query? and How? Sorry for asking too much but the kind of this query is new to me.

Comment: @MohammedAl-Ali - See my second edit. You can use sub-selects to combine these three statistics into a single query.